# How to improve movement code in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, mouseclick-event, flappy-bird-clone

I am making a game in Unity using the 2D format which has the same mechanics as Flappy Bird. But, I fail to make the movement as good as I want it to be.

The main problem is that when I press the mouse button, it does not stop until I release the button. I want with one click just one movement, so that if I press the mouse button down and don't let go the bird will drop. Because, it will bounce just once.

Here is the movement code, please tell me how to fix this issue. I have skipped some parts of the code which are not used in the movement.

```
float flapSpeed = 25f;
float forwardSpeed = 0.9f;

void Update () {
      if  (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) { 
          didFlap = true;
      }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
// Movement
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * forwardSpeed);
    if (didFlap) {
         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * flapSpeed);
         didFlap = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are checking if the mouse button is pressed all the time and reacting to it:

```
void Update () {
      if  (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) { 
          didFlap = true;
      }
}
```

You need to keep an additional flag which will allow a flap only after the mouse button has been released.  Something like:

```
private bool allowFlap = true;

void Update () {
      bool mouseDown = Input.GetMouseButton(0);
      if (allowFlap && mouseDown) { 
          didFlap = true;
          allowFlap = false;
      } else if (!allowFlap && !mouseDown) {
          allowFlap = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the mouseUp event? The only draw back is if people hold it down expecting it to fire the event rather than a simple click.

Comment: @insidesin Not sure about the `mouseUp` event (still pretty new to Unity), however I'm sure the OP is after a simple click interface.

Comment: Rather than implement up and down and lots of cases, I usually try implement a successful mouseUp. Though this isn't the case for all programs, just ones where users won't expect anything to happen unless they do a regular click.

Comment: @insidesin But aren't there restrictions on the type of objects that receive the `onMouseUp` event?

Comment: Perhaps there is. I honestly cannot remember down to that specific right now :P

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

You were calling `GetMouseButton` which runs once every frame the mouse button is down. Instead try calling `GetMouseButtonDown` which will fire once on each mouse down.

```
float flapSpeed = 25f;
float forwardSpeed = 0.9f;

void Update () {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
          GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * flapSpeed);
}

void FixedUpdate () {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * forwardSpeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same mechanics in Flappy Bird you need to work with the `rigitbody.velocity` instead of applying forces because it doesn't matter if the bird is going up, down or stopped, it will always fly up with the same initial speed.

```
private void HandleMouse ()
{   
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (rigidbody.velocity.x, velocityUp, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: One note, he is moving forward by `AddForce`, so if he sets `rigidbody.velocity` directly, the bird will stop going forward...

Comment: he wants to give his character a *push* upward, theres no reason `AddForce` cant get the job done

Comment: @RicardoReiter I added the horizontal velocity as you suggested

Comment: @Andrew Flappy Bird just applies an upward velocity in every touch, which can be done with `AddForce` as long as you cut the vertical velocity to 0 first. It's easier to just set the velocity instead

Comment: Cutting the `velocity` will make the animation un natural and it would look like the character hit an invisible wall. When you use a `Rigidbody` all the handling of the velocity is done for you, cutting `velocity` is unnecessary and your character falls by itself on its own gravity. I dont understand why you would want to do it this way.

Comment: In Flappy Bird it happens exactly in the unnatural way you described, it's like the bird hits an invisible ground and bounces when you touch (you don't see a U turn like a plane would do), and more importantly, it always goes up the same height, no matter what was the previous speed. I never said anything about removing the gravity.

Comment: Your still missing the point man, calling `AddForce` wont "make it do a U turn like a plane" it will react as though a *force was just added to it* such as a lunge upwards. To do a u-turn is to apply a gradual increasing force over time. `AddForce` gives an impulse of a force at once. The problem with cutting velocity is that it actually *does* take gravity out of the jumping equation, i.e. the speed at which you are falling actually should control the height u get from the next jump, where cutting the y velocity will make every jump look unnatural and the same, regardless of downward speed.

Comment: "will make every jump look unnatural and the same, regardless of downward speed". Yes, precisely, that's the objective because that's how Flappy Bird is. Maybe we are not agreeing then on what the Flappy Bird mechanics are.

Answer (score 0):

To get the mouse button clicked once, use GetMouseButtonDown.
Then you will need to apply an impulse instead of force, through the second param of AddForce(), ForceMode.Impulse:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * flapSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking Input.GetMouseButton(0) every frame. this function returns true if the player press and **hold** the button_0.
what you want is to check Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) which fires once.

by the way i have two advice for your code.

1. store return value of Input.GetMouseButtonDown() in a local
   variable so you only check it once every frame (each update loop
   itteration).
2. try to use GetComponent<>() on Start() function and store it in a
   global variable. because this function is not cost efficinet to be
   called every frame.